# How to marble test ngrx effect

Tags: unit-testing, ngrx-effects

I have the following ngrx effect

```
@Injectable()
export class StoreEffects {
    constructor(
        private store: Store<State>,
        private actions$: Actions,
    ) { }

@Effect()
userProfile$ = this.actions$
    .ofType('Load')
    .switchMap(action => {
        const payLoad = action['payload'];

        //Run code to load here

        return Observable.of({});  //Just for clarity I have simplified
    });
}
```

Now I want to unit test this, and came across the following documentation

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/testing.md

By following the documentation I came up with the following spec

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            HttpClientModule,
            StoreModule.forRoot({}) //I'm not sure why you need this, but if I dont supply this it does not work
        ],
        providers: [
            ProfileEffects,
            provideMockActions(() => actions),               
        ],
    });
});

it('should work', async () => {
    actions = hot('-a|', { a: {type: 'Load'}} });
    console.log('testing');
});
});
```

Now from what I understand whey I run the spec it should invoke my effect, but nothing happens and the test just runs to completion.  What am I doing wrong here?

I'm using Jamine.

Comment: Just to add to this, When I do the following it works

 effects = TestBed.get(ProfileEffects);
 effects.userProfile$.subscribe(result => {
             //Assertion here
            });

I'm not sure why I have to use subscribe since I'm providing a hot observable from the top.